# How long can a chair sit before wearing out?

Tags: materials

I'm mainly interested in aluminum or steel chairs here, as they're what I have lying around, but other materials could also be interesting to hear about if anyone has the data.

As I understand it, the chair exerts effort on the floor and the floor pushes back against the chair when it exists. So unlike a teapot orbiting Mars, for example, surely the surface must wear out over time.

I can't find anything that gives any sort of ballpark figure, but obviously they last long enough for nobody to complain about it. Not referring to long-term comfort while being used here ─ that's a different matter.

I doubt anyone is going to leave a chair in their garage for however long it takes to answer this question, so I'm also cool with anecdotal evidence. I've never put more than a few decades into a single chair before, so I don't have much personal evidence to go off.

Comment: An item at rest could theoretically last forever if there were nothing rubbing against it or reacting to its component materials.  Force doesn't wear things out, friction or chemical reaction does.  I'll start with a ballpark estimate of 200 years if it's in a good environment.

Comment: The chair legs bear a uniaxial load due to the weight of the seat and back, which means there's a deviatoric stress in the legs.  That deviatoric stress will be of the order of $10\,\mathsf{kPa}$, and so far, I've been unable to find any data on creep rates of steel and aluminium at deviatoric stresses lower than a few tens of megapascals, but there will _be_ a creep rate, which will eventually lead to enough permanent axial strain to declare the chair "worn out".

Comment: 200 years is nothing. If you live in a country that has some history (e.g. the UK or Europe) you can easily find (wooden) chairs and benches that are 500 years old or more, for example in old churches.

Comment: Static forces generally don't wear things out.